# Thread execution on android

Tags: android, multithreading

I think this is a beginner (me) question, then for you guys is easy to answer.

I have this method:

```
public void onQuantityTextChange(final int value)
{       
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            addProductToCart(value);

            view.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    updateTotals();
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}
```

My question is: this peace of code:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
  updateTotals();
}
```

is executed only when this `addProductToCart(value);` method is executed(finished)? or is it more safe to use `AsyncTask`s with `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: 1/ yes. 2/ both work. Asynctask basically does that, but with a lot of useful features. I recommend to always use asynctask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always executed after: `addProductToCart(value);`
But if that function starts a `Thread` or `AsyncThread` or similar then the function will return before that task finishes.

To summarize: nobody can answer without the contents of `addProductToCart`

Answer (score 0):

That largely depends on whether or not your method `addProductToCart(value)` starts another thread of its own. If it does, then there's no guarantee as the thread will start and finish as the system sees fit.  If not, then you will not call `view.post(...)` until that thread is complete.

Another thing to watch out for depending on what you're trying to accomplish is the method inside `view.post(...)` is not guaranteed to run immediately.  What this method does is put `Runnable` objects inside a message queue.  This means, this runnable won't execute until the other elements in the message queue execute first.  Secondly, the message queue can run at any time meaning even if this is the first `Runnable` in the queue it will start *eventually*, but not necessarily immediately.